# Configure differents resolution in mobile device

Tags: firefox-os, gecko, gaia

I am running Firefox OS on my Samsung S2.
I want to test my app with 240x320 resolution and 120dpi.
Is there any way to configure the resolution to 240x320 on my S2 phone?

While compiling Gecko or loading it or Gaia, I can tell the resolution, and apps will take that much area and the other part of screen is empty.
I read somewhere that we can give "b2g -screen 320x480@160 -profile" in the desktop version of Firefox OS and run apps in lower resolutions. I want to do that on the S2 phone.
Is there any way to do this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirty hack, but yeah:

- Make sure you can [debug certified apps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Using_the_App_Manager#Debugging_Certified_Apps)
- Open the App Manager and debug the System app
- Go to the styles tab and add the following to wrapper.css

*CSS:*

```
.appWindow {
    width: 240px !important;
    height: 320px !important;
}
```

And all new apps will also open in just 240x320 space.

Comment: Thanks Jan.
Is it possible that i can run that in my Phone. I mean use 240x320 area of my phone and left the other area. I tried changing wrapper.css file but it will not reflect in my phone. May be changing viewport height width will work as all the apps using viewport to set resolution. But dont know how to change thatm

Comment: File ncViewPortInfo.cpp contain some info but dont know now what to do.

Comment: This will work on the phone. Just attach the phone -> change the CSS and all apps will now occupy this space, remaining space stays empty. Just tested this myself.